# Element with name "Con" cannot be generated by XJC

Tags: netbeans, jaxb, xjc

Hello guys i have following problem when generating Java classes from XSD file. This is taken from PMML xsd file, where the element named "Con" is located. These two are the only places this element is used. Even with this smallest possible example it doesnt work.

```
<xs:element name="Neuron">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Con"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Con">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="from" type="xs:double" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When i try to generate classes with the name "Con" in there i get following error:

```
unable to write files: C:\myPathHere\build\generated\jaxbCache\PMML-4-3\org\dmg\pmml_4_3\Con.java (The handle is invalid)
```

Interestingly if i change the name of the element to anything else it is working without problem and all classes are generated correctly. Is there something im missing here? Sadly could not find anything related to name "Con" being excluded from valid element names in XSD for JAXB java class generation.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: On Windows (and MS-DOS), certain filenames such as 'con' have special meaning. Maybe that is a problem here. See this blog post from Microsoft: [What’s the deal with those reserved filenames like NUL and CON?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073)

Comment: Thanks didnt know about reserved filenames in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con is a reserved word for windows. You can't create Con.txt itself on windows. What you can do is customize the binding, give a different file name and use the `@XmlElement(name="Con")` annotation

See [Class Binding Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html#bnbbt) to customize the classname

Comment: Thanks didnt know about reserved filenames in Windows.